# How to target only the index page with jQuery/javascript?

Tags: jquery

What I did is actually I added some fade in effects for several divs with css3. At first it looks nice, but when you start browsing through the site it becomes annoying to see this effect so I decided not to get rid of the animations, but to leave it only for the main page. So, actually I have this jQuery code:

```
if (it is www.mydomain.com, but not www.mydomain.com/aaaa (or anything) ) {
$("#header").addClass("class1 class2 class3");

} else {
$("#header").removeClass("class1 class2 class3");
}
```

How to check if there is anything after mydomain.com/... or you can come up with a better solution?

I cant do this with css as I will be adding content to header.php file which is necessery for all of the pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're index page has a pathname of `/`, and that other pages have a pathname that is longer than one letter, you could do:

```
if (document.location.pathname.length > 1) {
     //do something
}
```

Or if your index page has a certain element that the other pages does not have, you can do:

```
if ($("#elementID").length) {
     //do something
}
```

or if you do :

```
<body class="index">
```

in your html, you can do:

```
if ($('body').is('.index'))  {
     //do something
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this option is sloppy becuase now u are checking for URI every page wasting resources rather than just including it on only the index page.

Comment: That is true, but most of us use one script file for an entire site, as that is considered better than including a different script on each page, and then you'll need some way to figure out what code to run where.

Comment: It is wordpress. All the pages use the same html header structure as it comes up from one file - header.php

Comment: well really, you use a templating engine, so that javascript includes are compiled per page...

Comment: Yes, so that is why I want to target URI and still do not know how to do it. I will give a try on if (document.location.pathname.length > 1) {
     //do something
}  but I am almost sure that it will be a downturn to performance

Comment: I don't much care for templating engines, personally I use one script file that is cached and used on all subpages, and believe that is the best way to do it. Since this is wordpress, just checking the URL is probably the simplest and best solution.

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
if (document.location.pathname.length > 1) {
     $("#header").addClass("fadeIn fadeIn-3s fadeIn-Delay-3s"); 
}
else {
  $("#header").removeClass("fadeIn fadeIn-3s fadeIn-Delay-3s"); 
}
});
</script>

Comment: I added this code, but I have an opposite effect. I have animations on all other pages but not on the main.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for URI

or

Make an index specific include for that javascript.

Second option way cleaner IMO.